# Render Cell into specific element?

Tags: javascript, celljs

Is it possible to render a `Cell` (from [CellJS](https://www.celljs.org/)) into a specific element? For example, if you wanted to render a `Cell` along with some static HTML not managed by `cell`. Or if I wanted to have 2 independent `Cell` apps on a single page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <header>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cell/1.1.1/cell.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var el = {
        $cell: true,
        $type: "div",
        $components: [
          // Components
        ]
      }
    </script>
  </header>
  <body>
    <h1>A CellJS App</h1>
    <div id="cell__container">
      <!-- RENDER CELL HERE -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't see anything in the docs that indicates how to do this. Or if its even possible.

Comment: Would this help https://tutorial.celljs.org#e-injecting-a-cell-into-an-exsiting-dom-tree? --- Include a `id` property in `el`, with `cell_container` as its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official API documentation](https://tutorial.celljs.org/#e-injecting-a-cell-into-an-exsiting-dom-tree) shows how you can insert components into an existing DOM tree.

> However sometimes you may not want to build an entire web page with Cell. You may just want to generate a small component with Cell and inject it into an existing DOM tree.

This can be achieved in two steps:

1. Set an `id` on the element you would like to inject into.
2. Include the same `id` in your Cell object definition.

Below is an example of two cell apps on one page:

```js
var el = {
  $cell: true,
  $type: "div",
  id: "cell_container1",
  $components: [{
    $type: "h1",
    $text: "Lorem"
  }, {
    $type: "a",
    $text: "Ipsum",
    href: "https://www.google.com"
  }]
};

var el2 = {
  $cell: true,
  $type: "div",
  id: "cell_container2",
  $components: [{
    $type: "h1",
    $text: "Dolor"
  }, {
    $type: "a",
    $text: "Sit",
    href: "https://www.google.com"
  }]
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cell/1.1.1/cell.min.js"></script>
<h1>A CellJS App</h1>
<div id="cell__container1">
  <!-- RENDER CELL HERE -->
</div>
<div id="cell__container2">
  <!-- RENDER CELL HERE -->
</div>
```

Comment: Hadn't seen this tutorial. Can you add a note to the solution mentioning an `id` to its more obvious for future searches?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody. I'm unsure if a class can be used also, or if it's limited to an `id`.